# How to make a digital clock using MSP430G2553?

Tags: clock, schematics, msp430, energia

I want to make a digital wall-clock as a small electronics project. Since I am very new to this stuff I want to just try to imitate some already completed projects so that I can learn from them.

I have a few sample pieces of the IC 553 and some other lower config ICS. I have basic soldering tools and am willing to spend some money on this project. I have ordered a new TIVA C board since my MSP launchpad has stopped working ( powers ON but the Energia IDE doesn't list it in the connected boards ) .

So if anyone can help me with it by either providing the sketches and circuit schematics for the MSP ( program using Energia ) or provide links that has the necessary steps, it would be really helpful.

I hope this does not violate any community guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you'll need:

1. Something to display the time on. This may be a set of 7-segment LED displays, a dot matrix LCD, etc...
2. A feature of the MCU called RTC *(Real Time Clock)*, sometimes also abbreviated as *Real Time Timer*. This will require a 32.768kHz Crystal, because in a clock, you really can't do without it.
   You could also use a dedicated RTC chip and hook it onto one of MCU's serial busses.
3. A means of powering it - be it a battery, a mains adapter, ...

Please forgive (or edit) me if I forgot something important.

Cheers.

**EDIT:**

Well, we are living in the age of SMD's, therefore breadboarding any custom chip is difficult. However, *breakout boards* are easy to come by.

These, for example, incorporate pretty high-end RTC chips. Feel free to read through the documentation.

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10160

http://www.adafruit.com/products/255

You simply hook 'em onto [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus), or [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) respectively.

---

Regarding your last question about schematics... Schematics is *always* very IC-dependant. I'll take the DS3234 chip as an example.

Clicking the *Datasheet* [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/DS3234.pdf) on the Sparkfun's website will lead you to the IC's very datasheet. You **need** to get used to this stuff. Luckily for you, Maxim/Dallas Semi has very descriptive and user-friendly documents. Right on the first page, there is a *Typical Application Circuit*, explaining what you need/can do with individual pins of the IC. However, if you get the PCB from Sparkfun, you will also need pinout of the carrier board itself. Get it via the *Schematics* link.

Anyway, green tick on this answer would be appreciated.

Cya!

Comment: if it is not too much to ask, can you please provide more details about the real time clock chip. like a schematics of the connections or a link to a relevant site. I did some research and learnt about the Display and most other necessary stuff. I currently use Arduino UNO to work on the project. once i am successful and get a MSP430 Launchpad I will adapt it to 553 IC. But for now I am unable to store and display the real time. That is where I need help.

Comment: You really need to look for stuff like this yourself. There are hundreds of RTC chips out there on the market. Just get on Digikey, Farnell, Mouser, Adafruit, Sparkfun and search :)
Datasheets will become your best friends after some time.

Comment: OK. I only wanted to know which would be the best as I didn't want to end up worrying over a defective part on y first project. Thanks any way .

Comment: One more help. Instead of buying a pre soldered board, I have ordered for some sample ICs. Even if I don't get them I am planning on buying them locally. So if you can help me find the schematics for interfacing the real time clock ICs with micro controllers such as ATmega or MSP30G2. Help me with this please.